# recursively examining the first element of the list to see if list contains given element

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I am stuck with this code because I cannot search for t list in `t.contains` method.

```
public static <T> boolean contains(T element, List<T> t) {

        if (t.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        } else if (t.contains(t) == element){
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: what are you trying to do ??

Comment: Why are you looking to see if the list contains the list as opposed to `t.contains(element)`?

Comment: What do you mean by  t list in t.contains method?

Comment: i am trying to see if the first element of the list contains the given element while recursively examining the list. t is the list and element if what i am trying to search for.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
t.contains(t) == element
```

you probably meant to say

```
t.get(0) == element
```

which is a check whether the first list element is the one you are looking for. After you sort that out, you must sort out the recursive call. This should involve

```
t.subList(1, t.size())
```

but note that this idiom is very impractical in Java and it will result in bad performance and memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
public static <T> boolean contains(T element, List<T> t) {
    return t.isEmpty()? false
         : t.get(0).equals(element)? true
         : contains(t.subList(1, t.size()));
}
```